# error in django on pythnonanywhere

Tags: python, django

i am learning django framework for python and following this tutorial.[Here](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/index.html)
but when i do pip install whitenoise on pythonanywhere but it spits out the following error.why is it so

[image]

Comment: Create virtualenvironment and activate it first http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/index.html#creating-a-virtualenv-on-pythonanywhere

Comment: @f43d65 i figured out this in the same console above when i rum python manage.py migrate it gives unknown comand:'migrate' why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install --user whitenoise
```

[InstallingNewModules](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/InstallingNewModules)

Comment: i figured out this in the same console above when i rum python manage.py migrate it gives unknown comand:'migrate' why?

Comment: what django version did you install ?

Comment: 1.8.2 version of django

Comment: `python -c import django; print(django.get_version())` , what is the output ?

Comment: the version i am using is 1.8.2

Comment: my mistake on the pythonanywhere server its 1.3.7

Comment: i guess i need to upgrade django version . am i right?

Comment: Since you are learning django you'd better stick to the version in the tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have no right to write in `/usr/...`. You should use a `Virtual Environment`, and thus those restrictions are removed because you'll be writing in folders you have permissions to write to.

[Here](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/deploy.html) is a good tutorial on creating a virtualenv on PythonAnyWhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can Write permission into the directory */../dist-packages/*

probaly the *sudo* command will work!

Try.. *sudo pip install whitenoise*

Let me know if you went ahead!!